# Integrate Custom built chatbot with Skype

Tags: rest, web-services, chatbot, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have built a chatbot having NLP and AI features in Java language. I have built restful webservices for interaction with the chatbot's AI engine.

The rest API will send the user's query and in return will get an answer by the bot.

I want to integrate this chatbot with Skype. As in there should be a chatbot account and then whenever a person types their query, it should be sent to my server via rest api call and then in turn the response message should be shown in skype chat window.

In my findings, I have seen skype integration with bots built bu Microsoft Bot Framework. Can anyone suggest how can I integrate this custom bot.

**If anybody feels I haven't added right tags to reach the exact audience, please add the tags.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a MS Chatbot (in Azure) which allows to deploy it on Skype (and other channels ie Teams), then define a WebHook to invoke your service.
This service needs to "speak" with the MS Bot framework, so you will need to serialise/deserialise the payload, but in the backend you existing endpoint can be used as you need.

Hope it helps.